# Create Sqlite Database from background without opening main app

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to create database from background without opening app.

Okay the scenario is

I am doing some stuff on location change in my app. I am registering with location manager on phone boot so suppose I have downloaded the app and I have not opened the app and my phone gets restarted so on boot complete receiver it will register for location change event in which I am handling database operation . So is it possible to do that ?

So My question is , Is it possible to create database without opening app? Is database need application environment to get created

Please accept my apology If I am not pretty clear

Comment: when u want to create d db...plz tell d exact scenario.../?

Comment: I am creating the database on location change event

Comment: implement LocationListener and check when loc!=null create d db.

Comment: opening app != displaying an activity

Comment: Yes thats true ..Thats why I am wondering why my App gets crashed. This problem came when some one installed the app and he has not opened it at all and location change triggered which access the database at that time it throws no such table exception

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create the database through one of your receivers.

Comment: But why application getting crashed with a exception no such table if app is not opened by user and location change triggered which access database

Comment: First you have to create your database. Note the BroadcastReceiver can only be alive for couple of seconds before it gets destroyed. So receive the intent in the receiver, and then start a Service to create the database and add the entry in the database.